# What's the best way to show that a link without the standard underline is clickable?

Tags: website-design, web-app

Specifically, I'm talking about the Quick Links textbox on the left.  While still maintaining the compactness of the box, how do I show that that text is clickable without putting an ugly underline underneath?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually Text links like the ones in your quick links section can be given a blue color in order to make them look more clickable. It is not really necessary to give blue color. You can always primary color of your software.

Refer to this [Making Clickable Elements Recognizable](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/clickable-elements/) article for more explanation.

I have made a quick wireframe for your quick links section which involves white background to make it look clean. I've used blue color for clickable notion along with an arrow suggesting that this link can be refered to some section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate your link with colors and put some animation or icons after your link name that shows there is clickable text.

For example:

[image]

It will help you to get rid of from ugly underline.